# Twitter API Postman: Code 32: Could not authenticate you

Tags: android, authentication, twitter, postman

I want to test the Twitter API for an app in the future. I was trying to test it with Postman but I get this error all the time.

> "code": 32,
> "message": "Could not authenticate you."

I made an new app from my developers account and put all the generated tokens into Postman like this:

[image: Postman_Screenshot2]

My parameters are the same like this screenshot: (with the correct tokens)

[image: Postman_Screenshot1]

Do I need to check something important?
I hope someone has already faced this problem or just can help me with this.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Under the "Authorization" tab in Postman, choose "Request Headers" from the "Add authorization data to:" drop down.

Useful reference:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I accept it because it solved my problem. unfortunately I have the same problem with an other api call. I chose Request Headers, but It gives me again code 32: Could not authenticate you

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23somerandomhashtag

Comment: @Peter I have the exact same problem... I'm able to authenticate on the /user_timeline endpoint but not on the /search endpoint. I'm digging in and will update if I can get a solution.

Comment: by giving OAuth 1.0, I got answer in postman ,but in localhost it shows "code": 32, "message": "Could not authenticate you." how could i resolve the prolem?

Comment: @Miles Did you solve this issue. I only get this error if I add query params to the query. If I hit the end point without any params, all works ok.

Comment: @wuf810 Nope. I punted and moved on. I got it working with fetch() in my app. Which is all that really matters I guess.

Comment: @wuf810 I had the same problem. For me it was changing the Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded like ryanulit answered that solved it.

Comment: Read every answer here and could not get this to work using Postman. As was the case with @Miles I eventually got it working correctly with Fetch. No idea why.

Answer (score 7):

Error 32 "Could not authenticate you" can also happen when the content of the tweet triggers the Twitter censorship filter.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone still having issues...

My problem was that the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header was not set for my POST request when testing with Postman.  Once I added that, all was well.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to check is the `!` character in the status that's being posted. Ensure it's encoded correctly.

See here for more details: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/6ILDt39anbs/gEwMVBNJLkYJ

Answer (score 1):

Follow the picture and you will get the correct return.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles encoding my `oauth_callback` param, fixing this helped.